# How do I disable Edge/Chrome from using Kerberos on a Mac?

Tags: google-chrome, microsoft-edge, kerberos

Is there a flag in Edge/Chrome where I can tell it to ignore Kerberos tickets?

Comment: Why do you need this?

Comment: I am confused.  As it is one must specifically go out of your way to enable Kerberos authentication within [Edge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/iis/www-authentication-authorization/kerberos-double-hop-authentication-edge-chromium#step-4-edit-the-configuration-of-the-group-policy-to-allow-for-unconstrained-delegation-when-authenticating-to-servers) and Chrome. I am not entirely sure I understand what problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: I have two AD accounts.  One is a regular account, one is privileged.  I have two Edge profiles for each account.  I only get kerberos tickets for the regular account.  This keeps messing up signing into the privileged account on it's own profile.  I want to disable kerberos for that profile.